# No provider for router in angular2 rc5

Tags: angular

in module.ts

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router'

    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule
      ],
      declarations: [ 
        AppComponent
      ],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

in component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 

import { GlobalService } from './global.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'cwf',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public homeConfig = {};

    constructor(private _router:Router, private _globalService: GlobalService){}
```

I am getting error since I am defining router in constructor to navigate the route. If I comment the constructor line it works fine. Where I need to add the provider and how.

Comment: Show us error please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RouterModule` needs to be imported

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
```

or as it's usually done

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

```
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing
  ],
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: imported routing , RouterModule still the same. Should I add any provider ?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. Can you please add the exact error message to your question?

Comment: export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path:'',component: HomeComponent },
    { path:'step1',component: Step1Component },
    { path:'personinvolved',component: PersonInvolvedComponent },
    { path:'vehicleinvolved',component: VehicleInvolvedComponent },
    { path:'additionalinfo',component: AdditionalInfoComponent },
    { path:'uploadattachment',component: UploadAttachmentComponent },
    { path:'**',component: NotFoundComponent },
]) This is what i have in routing

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Please edit your question and add the code there.